# It is possible in Python to create a file that is readable and editable?

Tags: python, file, file-handling

```
myfile = open("filename.txt", "a")
myfile.write("Hello, ")
name = input("Enter your name: ")
myfile.write(name)
myfile.close()
myfile = open("filename.txt", "r")
greet = myfile.read()
print(greet)
```

It is possible to simplify these lines without closing the file? That is, is there an argument for the `mode` parameter similar to a "wr"?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: r+ Open the file for reading and writing both

Comment: @S4eed3sm thank you.